# String manipulation for VML Path 2

Tags: java, string, string-matching, stringtokenizer, vml

I am trying to parse VML Path value (this post is not the same to [String manipulation for VML Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140101/string-manipulation-for-vml-path)). 
This has a more complicated path value to handle.
I have this String value

```
m@0,l@0@0,0@0,0@2@0@2@0,21600@1,21600@1@2,21600@2,21600@0@1@0@1,250,350,450,@5,xe
```

I have four commands here m, l, x, and e. The following sums up my goal.

```
m@0,
l
  @0 @0
  0 @0
  0 @2
  @0 @2
  @0,21600
  @1,21600
  @1@2
  21600@2
  21600@0
  @1@0
  @1,250
  350,450
  @5,
x
e
```

In code, I think the following is a very good representation.

```
String command_type = "m"        List<String, String> parameters =   add("@0", "0")  // because the y parameter is not specified I need to force it to 0
String command_type = "l"        List<String, String> parameters =   add("@0", "@0")
                                                                     add("0", "@0")
                                                                     add("0", "@2")
                                                                     add("@0", "@2")
                                                                     add("@0", "216000")
                                                                     add("@1", "216000")
                                                                     add("@1", "@2")
                                                                     add("21600", "@2")
                                                                     add("21600", "@0")
                                                                     add("@1", "@0")
                                                                     add("@1", "250")
                                                                     add("350", "450")
                                                                     add("@5", "0") //because the y parameter is not specified I need to force it to 0
String command_type = "x"        (can have no parameter )
String command_type = "e"        (can have no parameter )
```

Here are the things that I noticed from VML.

1. Commands are not preceded by a comma **,** (true to all vml commands except **m** which is the first command.
2. Parameters come in pairs (x and y pairs)

I saw this link [Java String.split() Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856916/java-string-split-regex) and  maybe it is possible to use regular expressions in retreiving the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
This function/method is only for each command (like m, l,  and other vml commands). If you want to retreive all parameters for all commands please implement your own method that iterates through all vml command with the vml parameter.

This is my solution for my question. It is enough for my needs. If you have more suggestions or better algorithms please do share. Thanks :-)

```
private List<List<String>> createStructuredParameterArray(String vmlParameter){

        int totalParameterCount = 0;

        String currentXorYParameter = "";
        List<String> listOfParameters = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean previousIsComma = false;
        boolean firstRun = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < vmlParameter.length(); i++){
            if (i != 0)
                firstRun = false;
            char nextChar = vmlParameter.charAt(i);
            if (nextChar == '@'){
                /**
                 * check the currentXorYParameter if it is a valid format already, 
                 * <br> if True - then proceed to handling the next parameter 
                 * <br> ex. from handling X parameter to Y parameter
                 * <br> ex. from handling Y parameter to X parameter  
                 */
                if (checkIfValidSingleParameter(currentXorYParameter)){
                    totalParameterCount++;
                    listOfParameters.add(currentXorYParameter);
                    currentXorYParameter = "";
                    currentXorYParameter= currentXorYParameter+nextChar;    
                }else{
                    currentXorYParameter= currentXorYParameter+nextChar;    
                }
                previousIsComma = false;
            }else if (nextChar != '@' && nextChar != ','){ //numeric character
                currentXorYParameter= currentXorYParameter+nextChar;
                previousIsComma = false;
            }else if (nextChar == ','){
                if (checkIfValidSingleParameter(currentXorYParameter)){
                    totalParameterCount++;
                    listOfParameters.add(currentXorYParameter);
                    currentXorYParameter = "";
                }else{
                    if (firstRun){
                        totalParameterCount++;
                        currentXorYParameter = "0";
                        listOfParameters.add(currentXorYParameter);
                        currentXorYParameter = "";
                        firstRun = false;
                    }
                }
                if (previousIsComma){
                    totalParameterCount++;
                    currentXorYParameter = "0";
                    listOfParameters.add(currentXorYParameter);
                    currentXorYParameter = "";
                }
                previousIsComma = true;
            }
            if ((i+1)==vmlParameter.length()){
                if (checkIfValidSingleParameter(currentXorYParameter)){
                    totalParameterCount++;
                    listOfParameters.add(currentXorYParameter);
                    currentXorYParameter = "";
                    /**
                     * check if parameterCounter is odd or even, 
                     * <br> if odd  - add additional "0" to make it even
                     * <br> if even - do nothing
                     */
                    if ((totalParameterCount % 2)==1){
                        listOfParameters.add("0");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ((listOfParameters.size()%2)==1){
            listOfParameters.add("0");
        }
        /**
         * Group the parameters by 2 in a List<String> object
         * <br>List<String> object
         *      <bR> object.add("\<value here\>"); => for x coordinate
         *      <bR> object.add("\<value here\>"); => for y coordinate
         * 
         * <br>Then create a list of all List<String> object created from above
         * <br> uncomment below if the desired result return value is as described above 
         */
        List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(listOfParameters.size()>1){
            int counter = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i<listOfParameters.size(); i++){
                String xyCoordinate = listOfParameters.get(i);
                if ((counter%2)==1){ //X coordinate
                    temp.add(xyCoordinate);
                }else if ((counter%2)==0){ //Y coordinate
                    temp.add(xyCoordinate);
                    result.add(temp);
                    //temp.clear();
                    temp = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return result;

    }
```